# How to match text tokens from a lookup table?

Tags: java, nlp, tokenize, text-processing, text-mining

I'm trying to do text preprocessing on Tweets. What I'm interested in is to match tokens from tweet's text to that of a lookup table. For example I have a table/dictionary of sentiments words and I want to check if a tweet contains one of those words.

My text preprocessing at the moment is the following:

1. Store the tweet's text in a String.
2. Tokenize the text at whitespace characters (`String.split(" ")`) and remove all numeric and weird characters tokens. Also I remove all mentions and stopwords. Then store the tokens in a String array.

This approach leads to some problems and here is the explanation:

- One straightforward approach is just to compare the tokens with the strings in the table and check if they match. That is okay but this leads to the next problem.
- I also want to check for if the text contains emoticons (which are also stored in a dictionary). Now that I already removed all weird characters tokens, I can't simply do the previous comparisons approach. One could say ok, then just don't remove the numeric and weird characters tokens, but this leads to the following problem.
- I also want to cluster the text, so keeping the numeric tokens (or urls) is not an option since it screws the clustering quality.
- Keeping two versions of the tokens has a memory problem since everything is duplicated.

I was wondering if there is a way to match stuff that doesn't require duplicating stuff. Maybe using regex?

Answer (score -1):

Why not check it the other way around. test the tweet string if it contains a string from your lut.

tweetstring.contains(lut[i])

or better

tweetstring.toLowerCase().contains(lut[i].toLowerCase())